# Store JWT tokens in React

Tags: reactjs, jwt

I wrote a react app which uses a REST API to handle its requests. This is going well, but since all endpoints are protected, they require a JWT Token for authentication.

I read a lot about how to store the actual token - I figured out that using localStorage is not recommended since any Javascript can access it.

My favorite plan would be to render the ID Token whenever the server serves a page (e.g like CSRF Token, the ID Token is included in the rendered page and then stored inside the state by React), however, all Javascript code is static and not rendered by the server, so there is no way to render the token inside the JS File itself.

I thought about rendering the token to a div and telling React to fetch it from there - but this also feels bad since the div itself is still visible for the user and can be accessed over JS. 
Another solution would be a token endpoint, where the user authenticates with the Session Token that stores his session (which is encrypted and not accessible for Javascript) to get a token which is then used by React.

I would like to ask if there are other ways to approach this or if the token endpoint is a bad idea in general or has any downsides (CSRF?).

Thanks a lot,

Comment: What about session storage?

Comment: I think the only difference between sessionStorage and localStorage is that sessionStorage is cleared after a user clears it/closes the window - unfortunately this does not really solve the problem with XSS, does it?

Comment: That token is anyways going to be visible in the network bar when you make a request, there is no point in not using local storage, a better approach would be to use a prefix with the token such as `Bearer {your token}`, your localstorage will not contain the prefix and you can make a server side request with the said prefix.